# Como inserir comandos e variáveis em um arquivo ".bat" através de um arquivo ".bat"

Tags: variáveis, batch, bat, comandos

Quero criar um arquivo ".bat" que crie outro arquivo ".bat". Sendo que o segundo arquivo ".bat" é um arquivo que recebe valores sendo armazenados em variáveis.

- A "bat pai", ou melhor, o arquivo ".bat" que eu vou executar para gerar um segundo arquivo ".bat" vou definir de **bat1** e o segundo arquivo ".bat" originário da **bat1** vou definir de **bat2**.
- **bat pai = bat1**
- **bat filha = bat2**

O melhor jeito que encontrei de criar uma **bat2** através de uma **bat1**, é usando o comando abaixo, dentro da **bat1**:

```
cd "C:\"Pasta_de_destino_da_Bat_nova" 
copy nul nome_da_bat.bat
echo >> nome_da_bat.bat "texto ou comando que quero colocar dentro da bat"
```

Sabendo disso, quando quero incrementar uma leitura de variável (setar a variável) e depois utiliza-lá faço da seguinte forma:

```
echo >> nome_da_bat.bat set /P nome="nome:"
echo >> nome_da_bat.bat "Meu nome é %nome%"
```

Ao executar a **bat1**, nas partes da **bat2** que possuem alguma variável, retornam todas as partes em branco, segue a print:

**- bat1:** [exemplo de código na **bat1**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fubrv.png)

**- bat2:** [exemplo de como aparece os códigos na **bat2**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWw1c.png)

O objetivo era que a **bat2** recebesse um nome e depois exibisse uma frase com esse mesmo nome, exemplo:

`set /P nome="João" -->> "Meu nome é João"`

Após a análise das imagens, fica visível que a **bat2** se torna inútil, pois os códigos estão incompletos.

Alguém tem alguma solução para este caso?

Comment: tente `echo >> nome_da_bat.bat "Meu nome é %%nome%%"`

Comment: O acréscimo do símbolo "%" em cada lado da variável foi o suficiente, agradeço a ajuda! :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Dentro do bat1 você vai colocar assim, ai é só executar o bat2

```
@echo off
>"bat2.bat" echo @echo off
>>"bat2.bat" echo set /P "nome=nome: "
>>"bat2.bat" echo echo Meu nome e %%nome%%
>>"bat2.bat" echo pause
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado! 